# How to exit from a stream reading loop, avoiding an additional empty loop?

Tags: c++

When the program enters in the `if` and then `break`, empty cout-s are printed again.

```
void Person::ShowRecords()
{
    std::ifstream data("Input.txt");

    while (true)
    {
        if (!data.good())
        {
            break;
        }

        Person person;
        data >> person;
        
        std::cout << "First Name: " << person.getFirstName() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Last Name: " << person.getLastName() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Phone number: " << person.getNumber() << "\n";
        std::cout << "EGN: " << person.getEGN() << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: Essentially, you need to check the stream status _after_ `data >> person`, not _before_.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks

Comment: @AlexandarZhelev `while (true) { if (!data.good()) { break; } ... }` should be `while (data.good()) { ... }` or simply `while (data) { ... }`  A better option is to move the declaration of `person` above the loop and then use `while (data >> person) { ... }` instead.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm opening a file also sets the stream's state, so checking `good` (or `bad`) before checking `data >> person` is OK in this case. However, the state should also be checked *after* `>>` and *before* using `person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think that the most didactic way of tackling stream input is:

```cpp
while (true) {
    // Read
    // Check (if fail then break)
    // Use
}
```

Notice the pattern: *infinite* loop with Read/Check/Use. Check is where we can exit the loop. First you read, than you check if the reading operation was successful or failed, than you can use the data or exit based on that.

Adapting this to your case:

```
void Person::ShowRecords()
{
    std::ifstream data("Input.txt");    
    while (true) {
        // Read
        Person person;
        data >> person;
        // Check
        if (!data) {
            break;
        }
        // Use          
        std::cout << "First Name: " << person.getFirstName() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Last Name: " << person.getLastName() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Phone number: " << person.getNumber() << "\n";
        std::cout << "EGN: " << person.getEGN() << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

The non didactic and probably more idiomatic way is:

```
void Person::ShowRecords()
{
    std::ifstream data("Input.txt");    
    Person person;
    while (data >> person) { // Read and, immediately after, Check
        std::cout << "First Name: " << person.getFirstName() << "\n"; // Use
        std::cout << "Last Name: " << person.getLastName() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Phone number: " << person.getNumber() << "\n";
        std::cout << "EGN: " << person.getEGN() << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexandarZhelev Remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem.